# How to bind json data to class with dependency injection like ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, configuration, ioptionsmonitor

This is my class :

```
public class entityClass
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string os { get; set; }
}
```

and this is my `appsetings.json` :

```
{
  "key1": {
    "id": "4",
    "os": "XP"
  }
}
```

Please help me to fix this:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        IConfiguration configur = new ConfigurationBuilder()  //using Microsoft Configuration
                .SetBasePath(@"C:\ConsoleApp26\").AddJsonFile("appsetting.json").Build();

        ServiceCollection service1 = new ServiceCollection(); //using Microsoft DependencyInjection
        service1.Configure<entityClass>(configur.GetSection("key1")); //Error

        var test = new ClassController();
        Console.WriteLine(test.id + "==>" + test.os);
    }
}

class ClassController
{
    private readonly IOptions<entityClass> _entity;            //using Microsoft.Extensions.Options;

    public ClassController(IOptions<entityClass> entity)
    {
        _entity = entity;
    }

    public entityClass YMethod()
    {
        var view = _entity.Value;
        return view;
    }
}
```

It's very convenient at ASP.NET Core but it doesn't happen on the console...

I want to get the right answer in exactly the same way...

This is exactly the style of the code I wrote in ASP.NET Core MVC

[image]

Comment: Shouldn't you be using a HostBuilder: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50728639/serilog-and-net-core-2-1-hostbuilder-configuration

Comment: Your code has "//Error" comment. And what us the error?

Comment: Also be sure to install `Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions` (if you don't want use the [generic hosting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/generic-host) which leverages all the needed packages)

Comment: @Guru-Stron Oh that was the problem Thank you very much my smart brother. im learning from youtube and i have many similar problem...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your provided code has **no error where you comment it** but 3 other:
[image]

Here is how to fix them:

1. You have to build an `IServiceProvider` and use that to create an instance of `ClassController`. To do so you also have to register that class to the `ServiceCollection`.
2. Call the `YMethod` from the `ClassController` instance to get an instance of `entityClass`.

```cs
service1.AddTransient<ClassController>();

var provider = service1.BuildServiceProvider();
var test = provider.GetRequiredService<ClassController>().YMethod();
```

Here is the final result

```cs
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Options;

namespace ConsoleApp1;

public class entityClass
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string os { get; set; }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        IConfiguration configur = new ConfigurationBuilder()  //using Microsoft Configuration
                .SetBasePath(@"C:\ConsoleApp26\")
                .AddJsonFile("appsetting.json")
                .Build();

        ServiceCollection service1 = new ServiceCollection(); //using Microsoft DependencyInjection
        service1.Configure<entityClass>(configur.GetSection("key1")); //Error
        service1.AddTransient<ClassController>();

        var provider = service1.BuildServiceProvider();
        var test = provider.GetRequiredService<ClassController>().YMethod();
        
        Console.WriteLine(test.id + "==>" + test.os);
    }
}

class ClassController
{
    private readonly IOptions<entityClass> _entity;            //using Microsoft.Extensions.Options;

    public ClassController(IOptions<entityClass> entity)
    {
        _entity = entity;
    }

    public entityClass YMethod()
    {
        var view = _entity.Value;
        return view;
    }
}
```

Comment: And the problem was completely solved...
Thank you very much for the thorough explanation and the time you took my bro

Comment: can I know why all parentheses have different color in your VS? ty

Comment: Well, I simply installed the [C# Dev Kit](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-dotnettools.csdevkit)

Comment: thank you <3 ; 
Can I ask one last question? ...
Why is there no difference between IOptions,IOptionsSnapshot and ISnapshut in this project? ...
I added { for(...),Thread.Sleep(...),Console.WriteLine(...) } in the last line...
and when running the program,When I make a change in json,I do not see the change in the program